# how to save the states of multiple toggle button

Tags: android, list, togglebutton

I have a list(with uncertain numbers of items) with toggle button. Every time I press back button, and enter that page again, all toggle button become off as state in xml. How can I get the position of the toggle button and "setChecked" it ? or any method to check the toggle button I checked (set to ON) before. Thank you.

Comment: Simple Solution is use SharedPreference

Comment: But my list have uncertain number of items.For example, my list is based on the data in database, items can be added or deleted. How to use sharedPreference?

Comment: Did my answer answer your question? if so, please accept.

Answer (score 0):

In the activity:

```
   private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
   }

   private void LoadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String strSavedMem1 = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM1", "");
    String strSavedMem2 = sharedPreferences.getString("MEM2", "");
    textSavedMem1.setText(strSavedMem1);
    textSavedMem2.setText(strSavedMem2);
   }
```

Use the Editor object to put the data in a key/value way, and the SharedPreferences object to retrieve them by their key.

Comment: my problem is every time I close that page and go back again...the state of toggle button will back to default..

Comment: Every time you toggle the button, save the state to the preference file. Every time you load the activity, load it (the toggle button value) from the preference file.